# Hashtables: Use previous property to generate next property

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Is there a way to generate a Hashtable that uses properties just defined in the hashtable to create the next property down the line?  I know I can just do it line by line instead, but I would like to maintain the formatting I currently have as I like how it reads.

```
$RequestedSpace = @{}
$RequestedSpace.Clear()
$RequestedSpace = @{
    Gb = (Read-Host "How much space (in Gb) would you like left over?")
    b = $RequestedSpace.Gb * 1Gb
};
$RequestedSpace.Gb
$RequestedSpace.b
```

The above results in a null value for $RequestedSpace.b

The below works, but is significantly uglier IMO

```
$RequestedSpace = @{}
$RequestedSpace.Clear()
$RequestedSpace.Gb = Read-Host "How much space (in Gb) would you like left over?"
$RequestedSpace.b = [bigint]$RequestedSpace.Gb * 1gb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that:

- you can define an *auxiliary variable* and use the assignment as an *expression* by enclosing it in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), which passes the assigned value through
- entries are defined in sequence, so subsequent entries can refer to aux. variables defined earlier.

```bash
@{
  # Note the *definition* of aux. variable $gb
  Gb = ($gb = [double] (Read-Host "How much space (in Gb) would you like left over?"))
  # Note the *use* of $gb
  b = $gb * 1Gb
}
```

Assuming you enter `2` when prompted, you'l get the following display output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Gb                             2
b                              2147483648
```

---

Note:

- The technique works for [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literals, as shown above (`@{ ... }`), as well as [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) literals (`[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`).
- [GitHub suggestion #13782](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13782) looks for a *built-in* way to allow hashtable entries to reference one another.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to mark this as the answer.  Sometimes I get stuck on something and just can't wrap my head around it and when I find the answer is so obvious I rush to finish what I was working on.  This worked very well, appreciate the response!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ThePostMan. No worries about the delay - I appreciate that you came back to accept an answer.